# When I pick a number in the list, the end result shows search found *and* not found

Tags: python

What do I need to add to stop it from doing that?

I need to sort a list = `[7, 5, 1, 2, 4]` and then use binary search to ask the user for the number.  The program should display `Search Found!` or `Search Not Found` depending on the user's input. If a user types `3`, program should display `Search Not Found!`. If a user types `7`, program displays `Search Found!`.

```
def bubble_sort(arr): #Used bubble sort to get it in ascending order
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        for j in range (len(arr)-1):
            if (arr[j]>arr[j+1]):
                temp = arr [j]
                arr[j] = arr [j+1];
                arr [j+1]= temp;
    return arr

def binary_search(target, arr): #Then binary search
    low=0
    high=len(arr)-1
    mid=0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        mid = int((low+high)/2)
        if target==arr[mid]:
            print("Search Found!!")
            break
            #I could be missing something here, not sure what?
        elif target<arr[mid]:
            high = mid-1
        else:
            low = mid+1
            print("Search Not Found")

#Whenever I run the end result shows search found and not found
def main():
    test = [7, 5, 1, 2, 4]
    print (bubble_sort(test))
    target = int(input("Type your search number: "))
    binary_search(target, test)

main()
```

Comment: You need to print `Search Not Found` only after the loop ends. Look up the `else` clause on `for` loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `else` clause should not be running throughout the whole loop, you should instead move it to the end of your loop:

```py
def bubble_sort(arr): #Used bubble sort to get it in ascending order
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        for j in range (len(arr)-1):
            if (arr[j]>arr[j+1]):
                temp = arr [j]
                arr[j] = arr [j+1];
                arr [j+1]= temp;
    return arr

def binary_search(target, arr): #Then binary search
    low=0
    high=len(arr)-1
    mid=0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        mid = int((low+high)/2)
        if target==arr[mid]:
            print("Search Found!!")
            return True
        elif target<arr[mid]:
            high = mid-1
        else:
            low = mid+1
    print("Search Not Found") # if we go through the whole loop and still not found, then print
    return False

#Whenever I run the end result shows search found and not found
def main():
    test = [7, 5, 1, 2, 4]
    print (bubble_sort(test))
    target = int(input("Type your search number: "))
    binary_search(target, test)

main()
```

You should also return `true` or `false` rather than using `break`.

#### Output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7]
Type your search number: 3
Search Not Found
...
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7]
Type your search number: 7
Search Found!!
```